# Is this a bug with CSS3: Rounded corners with CSS3 gradient

Tags: html, gradient, css

I'm running into an issue where the border of an outer div with rounded-corners is getting cut-off by an inner element with a CSS3 gradiet. Is this a bug with CSS3 - if so, I'll happily submit a bug-report.

If not, how do I fix this?

**Source & Demo here**:
http://jsfiddle.net/joshuamcginnis/2aJ8X/

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: it's a fairly common problem when you set the background on a different element to the rounded corners.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem isn't the gradient - give your `<h2>` element a solid background to see. Instead, you need to round the corners of the `<h2>` as well as of the wrapping `<div>`.

Add `border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;` and the appropriate vendor-specific versions to the `<h2>` styling and it all works.

Comment: This solution works for all browsers except IE. I only tried it in IE9, where the gradient fill seems to "flow over" the borders. (Or am I missing something?) See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692686/ie9-border-radius-and-background-gradient-bleeding

Comment: this solution is not good if the container has overflow:visible and it's scrollable, and i'm facing that problem RIGHT NOW...

Answer (score 2):

overflow:hidden; does not work

but this does:

```
h2
{
  position:relative;  
  z-index:-1;
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to background gradients. It's just the background of the h2 element overlapping sitting on top of the rounded corners. I'm not **sure** it's a bug in the strictest sense, but it is fairly well known. Easiest 'fix' is rounding the corners of the element with the background. [Example: just setup for chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/2aJ8X/1/)