# IE9 round corners and filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I used `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` to get gradients for IE <9.
Now, when combined with a shadow, or a different background underneath, I get box sticking out.

Is there a way to keep backwards-compatibility, without conditionals and external stylesheets?

See code:

```
.class {
    float:left; 
    border:solid 1px #AAA; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1; 
    text-align:left; 
    width:350px; 
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px; 
    background:#FFFFFF; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #BBBBBB; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#f5f5f5, endColorstr=#FFFFFF); 
}

<div class="class">this</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use conditionals and extra stylesheets? I've been using a main stylesheet for the latest IE and other browser and then conditionals to include overrides for older IE version and it has been working very well for me like this. The average user (latest IE or other browser) will just get 1 stylesheet, and people with older IE will get 1 additional stylesheet, which makes just 2. I don't see the issue.  Can you tell me why you wouldn't want to do this?

Comment: Stuff I use it with comes with auto-templating which makes use of any browser specific css very problematic. It is due to interfacing, (almost) all css tasks are done via wysiwyg managers. That requires working with one auto-generated css stylesheet. Anything done outside of templating engine, has to be adjusted by hand and that I cannot have. Just to wrap it up. I have to stuff all css into one all-rounder stylesheet. Pity thou that MS screwed up again - in reverse. And this IE9 was supposed to be their big comeback into world of standards. I just do not any big hooha in IE9. Lotsa marketing.

Comment: They cannot even make their own household work with each other nicely. Every new generation do not care for previous ones.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692686/ie9-border-radius-and-background-gradient-bleeding

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd recommend (to everyone ever!) using [Paul Irish's technique](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) which looks like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <body class="ie6"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <body class="ie7"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <body class="ie8"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <body class="ie9"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <body> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

in your HTML.

Then in your CSS you can write things like:

```
#someID {
    color:lawngreen;
}

.ie6 #someID {
    color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.ie8 #someID, .ie9 #someID {
    color:saddlebrown;
}
```

to target different IEs. It's an easy technique that solves a lot of problems (no extra HTTP requests, an negligible extra code for all browsers).

Comment: But this is still conditionals. IE9 was supposed to be strict standards. Also my answer to Bazzz, to clarify why conditionals are out. Thank you for your time.

Comment: On the other hand ... when at a second glance ... nice technique. But it would take me forever to rewrite templates - even if my boss would agree to pay for it. Thanks again for this and your time Rich.

Comment: It doesn't break anything byadding the body bit, and is only a find replace away.

Answer (score 10):

I lost my corners’ radius once I applied `filter: progid:DXImageTransform Microsoft.gradient...`. I suppose it’s a similar problem.

To solve it, I used an SVG background generated here
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

It’s simpler than it sounds. In CSS, it looks like

```
body.ie9 div.test  {
   border-radius:10px  
   background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz...
```

and lo, round corners and gradient.

$2c,
*-pike

Comment: errr, which is a dupe answer from here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692686/ie9-border-radius-and-background-gradient-bleeding ...sorry.

Comment: This works really well, thanks! My buttons on IE9 have now got a gradient and rounded corners just like Firefox, Chrome etc.

Comment: Wow, nice!  Best answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I find when IE is giving me issues with stuff pushing out of the round corners, I nest that inside another element...

So for example I would put the round corners and drop shadow on the outer element with the size I want and overflow: hidden; Then put the gradient on another element inside. 100% fit.

maybe not the perfect solution, but fairly simple.