# Gradient in Internet Explorer 9 overflows the rounded border

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners, radial-gradients

I'm having a problem with rounded borders and a gradient in IE9. The gradient overflows the rounded border.

```
.cn_item:hover, .selected{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:49px;
    color:#333333;
    padding:5px;
    margin:6px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;       
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD 25%, #FF0000 5%);        
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#666666');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#666666')";
    zoom: 1;

    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

I already use the `overflow:hidden;` but nothing works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug. If you search stackoverflow there are some questions just like this one.
[IE9 border-radius and background gradient bleeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692686/ie9-border-radius-and-background-gradient-bleeding)

The only way around it without adding more markup is to use svg.
[Colorzilla gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) should make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a wrapper div (rounded & overflow hidden) to clip the radius for IE9. Simple, works cross-browser. No need for SVG, PIE, JS, or conditional comments.

```
<div class="ie9roundedgradient"><div class="roundedgradient">text or whatever</div></div>

.ie9roundedgradient { 
display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; 
}
.roundedgradient { 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; 
/* use colorzilla to generate your cross-browser gradients */ 
}
```