# Why show the corners despite border-radius applied in IE and earlier?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I have a problem but not exactly with the border radius, but amm not know how to explain but I put 2 images as seen in chrome, firefox, etc and another image of as seen in IE9 and earlier.

**CHROME and Others browsers**

[image]

**IE9 and earlier**

[image]

Seems that despite applying the border-radius, still show those corners.

```
aside#sidebar ul {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
}
aside#sidebar ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    //border: 3px solid white;
}
aside#sidebar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    background: transparent;
}
```

**EDIT**

Does it have something to do this part? Background used for each item in the list, and this is the background of the first

```
aside#sidebar #itemLinea1 {
    //border-color: #DE9E26;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,234,187,1) 0%, rgba(252,205,77,0.75) 50%, rgba(248,181,0,0.75) 51%, rgba(251,223,147,0.5) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(252,234,187,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(252,205,77,0.75)), color-stop(51%,rgba(248,181,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(251,223,147,0.5)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,234,187,1) 0%,rgba(252,205,77,0.75) 50%,rgba(248,181,0,0.75) 51%,rgba(251,223,147,0.5) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,234,187,1) 0%,rgba(252,205,77,0.75) 50%,rgba(248,181,0,0.75) 51%,rgba(251,223,147,0.5) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,234,187,1) 0%,rgba(252,205,77,0.75) 50%,rgba(248,181,0,0.75) 51%,rgba(251,223,147,0.5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252,234,187,1) 0%,rgba(252,205,77,0.75) 50%,rgba(248,181,0,0.75) 51%,rgba(251,223,147,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fceabb', endColorstr='#80fbdf93',GradientType=0 );
    transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s linear;
}
```

At what should be?

Comment: Try adding border-radius:12px;  - the other two are specific to webkit and mozilla browsers

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code and it appears to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/87R5b/1/  I tested it in IE9.

Comment: Can you see the edited post please?

Comment: Which element has the ID of "itemLinea1"?

Comment: Is the first element of the list, is the color gradient yellow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an IE filter to apply a gradient to your elements. Unfortunately, these filters will not be clipped by `border-radius` as they are not painted on the box's background, whether you're applying `border-radius` to the same elements or their containers.

If you need to apply a gradient background, your best bet is to use a background image. If you only need to support IE9, ditch the filter and keep the SVG background image.

Comment: Yeah. works! Just leave the first line that is the SVG image. Thanks!!

Comment: More info about border-radius and gradient bleeding in IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692686/ie9-border-radius-and-background-gradient-bleeding

Answer (score 0):

Try using just border-radius, you need the core one, not just to target firefox and webkite, otherwise it is because those earlier browsers either don't support border radius, or you aren't using the proper prefix, -ms- for microsoft

Comment: I use only border-radius and did not work, then place-ms-border-radius and neither worked!

Comment: IE9 supports `border-radius`.  There is no need to use an -ms- prefix or to remove the Firefox and Webkit prefixed properties.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're applying rounded corners to the `a` element, but are assigning the background color to the underlying `li` element.  So you have a rounded rectangle sitting on top of a non-rounded rectangle with a colored background.  Hence, the corners of the non-rounded rectangle stick out.

Compare these two fiddles:

Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/87R5b/2/
Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/87R5b/3/

In the second one, I applied the yellow gradient to the `a` element instead.  That's just one possible solution, but it should work for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is correct, but I already had the code that way. The ID's have placed them in the 'a' and not the 'li'.. the solution es only used the first line of background.. the img svg! But thanks!